# How to change back color of a column when value changes in it with respect to previous column value.(Conditional styling)

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

I have a Column measure in Cross tab which needs to be styled diffrently when column value changes.For Instance my current output looks like this

[image]

I am trying to color the column in this manner

[image]

Output format here is xls.

SHIPCITY is a parent column header under which there are SHIPADRESS below that header.

Below is the jrxml that produces the current output.you can reproduce the issue using it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.0  -->
<!-- 2017-09-04T18:07:58 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ConditionalStyling" pageWidth="1400" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="1400" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" isIgnorePagination="true" uuid="c83c5a57-1109-4513-a122-d0bfbf7fd308">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Sample DB"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <style name="Crosstab_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CG" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CT" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#005FB3">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Style1" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#F7211E"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select * from orders   order by customerid, shipcountry , shipcity , shipaddress ]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ORDERID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="CUSTOMERID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="EMPLOYEEID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="ORDERDATE" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="REQUIREDDATE" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="SHIPPEDDATE" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="SHIPVIA" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="FREIGHT" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="SHIPNAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SHIPADDRESS" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SHIPCITY" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SHIPREGION" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SHIPPOSTALCODE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SHIPCOUNTRY" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <summary>
        <band height="300">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.HorizontalRowLayout"/>
            <crosstab>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="1400" height="300" uuid="34cf7e8d-c567-485d-85a7-798c27118f97">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.HorizontalRowLayout"/>
                </reportElement>
                <crosstabHeaderCell>
                    <cellContents>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="40" uuid="de2c1860-2c17-451c-93c1-691b7a2d52c6"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[CUSTOMER_ID]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabHeaderCell>
                <rowGroup name="CUSTOMERID" width="90">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{CUSTOMERID}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20" uuid="5b8cdacd-7f44-4dcf-8db0-6b6c58c3fb32"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{CUSTOMERID}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" uuid="08c3c9ff-49ec-435c-9fb9-10a97aeb16ff"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Total CUSTOMERID]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <columnGroup name="SHIPCITY" height="20">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{SHIPCOUNTRY}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement style="Style1" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="f68a5ef8-d957-4568-b895-93907688b107"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{SHIPCITY}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CG">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" uuid="9893aa3b-7eae-42de-b18d-30a92e1e6580"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Total SHIPCITY]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                </columnGroup>
                <columnGroup name="SHIPADDRESS" height="20">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{SHIPADDRESS}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.HorizontalRowLayout"/>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="969f7bc4-600e-4310-aa3f-526c278b6fde"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{SHIPADDRESS}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="08ba2a79-077d-4f94-bc55-62939d55e557"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Total SHIPADDRESS]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                </columnGroup>
                <measure name="ORDERID_MEASURE" class="java.lang.Integer">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{ORDERID}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <crosstabCell width="100" height="20">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CD">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="2ea2bac8-82f5-42b8-a6fe-2a397cadc9b2"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{ORDERID_MEASURE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" columnTotalGroup="SHIPADDRESS">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="46cc1294-ec97-4dcf-9189-f77fb9e87538"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{ORDERID_MEASURE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" columnTotalGroup="SHIPCITY">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CG">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="4bade212-3c6d-4027-bb5f-9e22ee527401"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{ORDERID_MEASURE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="CUSTOMERID">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="58c77e0a-d003-4f5f-9f0e-8f6e0e5a12d5"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{ORDERID_MEASURE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="CUSTOMERID" columnTotalGroup="SHIPADDRESS">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="163a57aa-ff00-4362-b078-8106fb513043"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{ORDERID_MEASURE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="CUSTOMERID" columnTotalGroup="SHIPCITY">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="de152f44-e188-42ef-9e22-7e8346e0f860"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{ORDERID_MEASURE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
            </crosstab>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

I can create the two conditions but could not think of logic to apply in conditional expression. Any thoughts on how i can achieve such conditional styling?

Comment: What have you already tried? It is better to post the small *jrxml* to reproduce your problem

Comment: @AlexK I have changed the example so that anyone can reproduce the issue using Sample DB and jrxml. I could make those styles but couldn't  think of logic for conditional styling. How do i detect the value have been changed? w.r.t previous column ( country name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was but tricky.I added one more column in my SQL for coloring.Using dense_rank() function i gave rank to the results and grouped them on country name. So basically those rows which has same country name have same rank and then i ordered this based on country name.

On the jasper side. I added this coloring column in column group and set its width to zero and then added my conditional style logic to the odd and even values. This is the logic i was looking for.